# Drawing a lot of lines and other shapes in WinRT App

Tags: c#, canvas, windows-runtime, windows-8.1

In my WinRT app I need to draw about 3000 objects on a canvas, where I can translate and zoom the view. Unfortunatley, after adding about 1500 lines to my canvas my Windows 8 App always crashes. What could be the best practice to achieve this?

One solution could be rendering everything on an image (how do I do this?). But then I loose comfort of easy access and editing of every element.

Also my scale and translate is very slow. But since I also need a big overview, it makes no sense to put only the objects of the visible area in the canvas, since on minimum zoom it's still everything and zoomed it's still very laggy cause of add and remove operations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple of different things you should employ to have a smooth UX:

Use a [Quadtree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadtree), whenever you add a shape to your canvas you also put it on your Quadtree. This will be helpful when you will zoom on a portion of the image: you will know what objects are in this portion of the image; you will render them again (against using a cached/pixellated version).

[image]

To overcome the potentially lengthy drawing process you could do the following:

- display the portion of the cached image overview at the right scale
- use a progress indicator to let know the user that the program is working render this portion
- when the faint rendering is done, blit it on the screen

A concrete example: [Google Maps](https://maps.google.com/) does that.